# Why are paths represented by strings and not a separate class?

Tags: c#

In C#, paths are usually represented by a string and then operated upon by static methods from the static Path class. Why isn't there a class like `java.nio.file.Path` instead? Such a class would naturally handle platform independent path separators for example.

I'm not asking for a library that implements a (non-static) Path class. I'm asking why the standard library has been designed that way.

Comment: You might be better off asking the developers of the language rather than StackOverflow... ;)

Comment: Because *probabbly* multiplatform wasn't a *core* requirement for .NET team, like it was for Java.

Comment: You could also just use `Path.Combine()`, if you don't want to mess with separators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they had to make a design choice, and they chose that one.  It occurs, though, that lots of java file-related classes (`FileReader`, `FileOutputStream,` etc) *also* use just a string. It is clear, simple, and gets the job done.

For things like path separators: the `Path` class in .NET has utility methods for that.

Comment: "Because they had to make a design choice, and they chose that one." I know that. My question is *why* did they make that choice.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt I *suspect* that is an impossible question to answer, other than "it didn't seem worth the complication, and the utility methods on `Path` do the job just fine"